# keyup Uppercase on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onkeyup

I would like to have an input that would change to upper case on `keyup`. So I attach a simple event on `keyup`.

HTML

```
<input id="test"/>
```

Javascript (with jQuery)

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

But I found that in Chrome and IE, when you push left arrow, the cursor automatically move to end. I notice that I should detect if the input is letter only. Should I use keycode range or regexp for detection?

Example: http://jsbin.com/omope3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can use the following (this is probably faster and more elegant):

```
<input style="text-transform: uppercase" type='text'></input>
```

But that sends the as-typed value back in the form data, so use either of the following to store it as all-caps in the database:

MySQL: `UPPER(str)`

PHP: `strtoupper()`

Comment: An added advantage to this method is that the user only sees all-caps text being entered, and doesn't have to watch his / her typed text turn into upper-case, as with using the Javascript method.

Comment: +1, the true-value could also be converted to uppercase in the onsubmit event of the form, before the data is sent to the server.

Comment: +1, better answer than mine.  I didn't know about this text-transform option, is it fully cross-browser?

Comment: We can use this plus an on blur uppercase method to work around. 

    $("#test").css('text-transform','uppercase').blur(function(){ 
          this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, if you use the text-transform: uppercase; css property:

```
<input id='test' style='text-transform: uppercase;' type='text'></input>
```

And with jQuery help you choose the **blur event**:

```
$("#test").blur(function(){
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

With this solution, you don't have to upper the database fields, you can use the cursor for movement and the user can insert/rewrite the text in the input field.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<input onkeyup="MakeMeUpper(this)" type="text"/>
```

And in your JS Code Part put:

```
function MakeMeUpper(f, e){ 
  var actualValue = f.value;        
  var upperValue = f.value.toUpperCase();
  if( actValue != upperValue){
    f.value = upperValue;       
  }   
}
```

This code won't change the text if the user entered something that is not text (left or right arrow).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, looks like some browsers move the cursor to the end when the value gets updated.  You could do this:

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){
  var upper = this.value.toUpperCase();
  if (this.value != upper) 
      this.value = upper;
});
```

which will only change the value if it needs to be changed.  However, that still leaves you with the problem that if you type `abd`, move left, hit `c` to get `abcd`, the cursor will still get moved to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (with jQuery)

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: This is good, but you may require this.val() instead of this.value().

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = $(this).val();
if (evt.keyCode != 37 && evt.keyCode != 39)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
    $(this).val(str);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to look at keyCode in your keyup function.

```
var UP_ARROW = 38,
    DOWN_ARROW = 40;

$('#test').keyup(function(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode == UP_ARROW)
    {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    }

    if (evt.keyCode == DOWN_ARROW)
    {
        this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    }
});
```